# Отключение и включение переноса тегом <br> для мобильных устройств

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет
Есть HTML

```html
<h4>Запись на тренировки: <br id="break">8-962-***-**-**</h4>
```

Как сделать, чтобы  номер телефона переносился на новую строку только для мобильных устройств?

Я попробовал придать в основном css свойство **display:none** для этого **br**.
Он исчез, если смотришь с компа.
Но даже если в

```html
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {display:block }
```

ставим **display:block**, например, то с телефона он не появляется

Answer (score 1):

Поместите номер телефона в тег `<span class="forMobile"></span>` А дальше просто меняйте значение `display` по медиа выражениям `display:inline-block;` а для мобильных  `display:block;` Это будет семантически более корректно, чем засовывать в параграф `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

У вас в медиазапросе не было элемента, которому вы назначаете  `display:block;`
Ну и как правильно заметили, лучше `span` используйте.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  span {
    display:block; 
    }
 }
```

```html
<h4>Запись на тренировки: <span id="break">8-962-***-**-**</span></h4>
```